# Titanium - Json Object Returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, json, titanium

My WEC webservice returning a JSON object and i want to use it in my Titanium app, but the problem is, there are array inside the JSON object, i can see them in the console but when i am trying to access by providing index, its not working.

**Example**

```
{
    "GetDoctorFavoriteTestResult": "{\"CountryList\":null,\"AddressDetails\":null,\"CollectionAddressDetails\":null,\"CourierAddressDetails\":null,\"labAddressDetails\":null,\"TestDetails\":[{\"TestID\":29,\"TestName\":\"CEA-Carcino Embryonic Antigen, serum\",\"Row\":0,\"LabID\":0,\"DoctorPatientMappingId\":0,\"PatientId\":0,\"TestDesc\":\"Colonic cancer marker.\\n\\nNote\\n1. This test is not recommended for cancer screening in the general population.\\n2. False negative / positive results are observed in patients receiving mouse monoclonal antibodies for diagnosis or therapy.\\n3. Patients with confirmed carcinoma may show normal pre-treatment CEA levels. Hence this assay, regardless of level, should not be interpreted as absolute evidence for presence or absence of malignant disease. The assay value should be used in conjunction with fi\",\"TestPrice\":0.0,\"BasePrice\":0.0,\"DiscountPrice\":0.0,\"Currency\":null,\"SampleAtHome\":false,\"IsActive\":false,\"LabName\":null,\"TestPerformedLabName\":null,\"Link\":null,\"TestResult\":null,\"UploadedTestFile\":null,\"PatientName\":null,\"TestRemarks\":null,\"ResultType\":null,\"TestFavouriteId\":0,\"CollectionPrice\":0.0,\"TotalPrice\":0.0,\"PaymentToECL\":0.0,\"PaymentFromECL\":0.0,\"ToBeListed\":true,\"OrderAmt\":0.0,\"AfterDiscountPrice\":0.0,\"CollectionType\":0,\"PreferedDate\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"PreferedTime\":null,\"SpecialInstructions\":null,\"PaymentType\":0,\"PaymentTypeStatus\":null,\"PaymentStatus\":null,\"CourierAddressId\":0,\"CollectionAddressId\":0,\"OrderId\":0,\"OrderDetailId\":0,\"BookedDateTime\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"ModifiedDate\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"PreviousSlotDateTime\":null,\"CategoryID\":0,\"TestCode\":null,\"CPTCode\":null,\"Abbrevation\":\"CEA\",\"MethodID\":0,\"SampleTypeID\":0,\"SampleTypeDesc\":null,\"TempId\":0,\"Description\":null,\"TAT\":null,\"TestType\":0,\"SampleOptions\":null,\"IdCountry\":0,\"IdState\":0,\"IdCity\":0,\"MethodName\":null,\"CategoryName\":null,\"TestCondition\":null,\"HyperLink\":null,\"ReferenceValue\":null,\"Units\":null,\"ReportAttributes\":null,\"OrderStatus\":null,\"TestAvailableHome\":false,\"PathologistId\":0,\"PathologistName\":null,\"TechnicianName\":null,\"PathologistSign\":null,\"TechnicianSing\":null,\"EmailId\":null,\"LabEmailId\":null,\"SampleCollectedDate\":null,\"ReportUploadedDate\":null,\"IsExists\":false},{\"TestID\":73,\"TestName\":\"Family Finder + Y-DNA67\",\"Row\":0,\"LabID\":0,\"DoctorPatientMappingId\":0,\"PatientId\":0,\"TestDesc\":\"Family Finder + Y-DNA67\",\"TestPrice\":0.0,\"BasePrice\":0.0,\"DiscountPrice\":0.0,\"Currency\":null,\"SampleAtHome\":false,\"IsActive\":false,\"LabName\":null,\"TestPerformedLabName\":null,\"Link\":null,\"TestResult\":null,\"UploadedTestFile\":null,\"PatientName\":null,\"TestRemarks\":null,\"ResultType\":null,\"TestFavouriteId\":0,\"CollectionPrice\":0.0,\"TotalPrice\":0.0,\"PaymentToECL\":0.0,\"PaymentFromECL\":0.0,\"ToBeListed\":true,\"OrderAmt\":0.0,\"AfterDiscountPrice\":0.0,\"CollectionType\":0,\"PreferedDate\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"PreferedTime\":null,\"SpecialInstructions\":null,\"PaymentType\":0,\"PaymentTypeStatus\":null,\"PaymentStatus\":null,\"CourierAddressId\":0,\"CollectionAddressId\":0,\"OrderId\":0,\"OrderDetailId\":0,\"BookedDateTime\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"ModifiedDate\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"PreviousSlotDateTime\":null,\"CategoryID\":0,\"TestCode\":null,\"CPTCode\":null,\"Abbrevation\":\"Family Finder + Y-DNA67\",\"MethodID\":0,\"SampleTypeID\":0,\"SampleTypeDesc\":null,\"TempId\":0,\"Description\":null,\"TAT\":null,\"TestType\":0,\"SampleOptions\":null,\"IdCountry\":0,\"IdState\":0,\"IdCity\":0,\"MethodName\":null,\"CategoryName\":null,\"TestCondition\":null,\"HyperLink\":null,\"ReferenceValue\":null,\"Units\":null,\"ReportAttributes\":null,\"OrderStatus\":null,\"TestAvailableHome\":false,\"PathologistId\":0,\"PathologistName\":null,\"TechnicianName\":null,\"PathologistSign\":null,\"TechnicianSing\":null,\"EmailId\":null,\"LabEmailId\":null,\"SampleCollectedDate\":null,\"ReportUploadedDate\":null,\"IsExists\":false},{\"TestID\":69,\"TestName\":\"Family Finder (For Both)\",\"Row\":0,\"LabID\":0,\"DoctorPatientMappingId\":0,\"PatientId\":0,\"TestDesc\":\"Family Finder (For Both)\",\"TestPrice\":0.0,\"BasePrice\":0.0,\"DiscountPrice\":0.0,\"Currency\":null,\"SampleAtHome\":false,\"IsActive\":false,\"LabName\":null,\"TestPerformedLabName\":null,\"Link\":null,\"TestResult\":null,\"UploadedTestFile\":null,\"PatientName\":null,\"TestRemarks\":null,\"ResultType\":null,\"TestFavouriteId\":0,\"CollectionPrice\":0.0,\"TotalPrice\":0.0,\"PaymentToECL\":0.0,\"PaymentFromECL\":0.0,\"ToBeListed\":true,\"OrderAmt\":0.0,\"AfterDiscountPrice\":0.0,\"CollectionType\":0,\"PreferedDate\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"PreferedTime\":null,\"SpecialInstructions\":null,\"PaymentType\":0,\"PaymentTypeStatus\":null,\"PaymentStatus\":null,\"CourierAddressId\":0,\"CollectionAddressId\":0,\"OrderId\":0,\"OrderDetailId\":0,\"BookedDateTime\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"ModifiedDate\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"PreviousSlotDateTime\":null,\"CategoryID\":0,\"TestCode\":null,\"CPTCode\":null,\"Abbrevation\":\"Family Finder (For Both)\",\"MethodID\":0,\"SampleTypeID\":0,\"SampleTypeDesc\":null,\"TempId\":0,\"Description\":null,\"TAT\":null,\"TestType\":0,\"SampleOptions\":null,\"IdCountry\":0,\"IdState\":0,\"IdCity\":0,\"MethodName\":null,\"CategoryName\":null,\"TestCondition\":null,\"HyperLink\":null,\"ReferenceValue\":null,\"Units\":null,\"ReportAttributes\":null,\"OrderStatus\":null,\"TestAvailableHome\":false,\"PathologistId\":0,\"PathologistName\":null,\"TechnicianName\":null,\"PathologistSign\":null,\"TechnicianSing\":null,\"EmailId\":null,\"LabEmailId\":null,\"SampleCollectedDate\":null,\"ReportUploadedDate\":null,\"IsExists\":false}],\"ExistingMappedTest\":null,\"AllTestDetails\":null,\"CountryPrices\":null,\"PriceComponents\":null,\"OrderedTestDetails\":null,\"BookedSlots\":null,\"LabScheduleDetails\":null,\"ReturnValue\":0,\"ReturnMessage\":null,\"TotalRecords\":0,\"Rows\":0,\"IsActive\":false}"
}
```

Here i am able to access the **GetDoctorFavoriteTestResult.CountryList** by using **JSON.parse** but when m trying to get the array **GetDoctorFavoriteTestResult.TestDetails** it showing it as empty.

Webservice is running perfect even in the browser.

again, i can see the array data in the Titanium console window.

Any solution ?

Comment: Have you chrome installed on PC or mac?

Comment: PC, working for the android for now.

Comment: Chrome ?
I am talking about the titanium,
Yeah i tested the service in chrome and firefox, but the data is same.

Comment: I have the chrome, now what to do?

Comment: Can you show the code around GetDoctorFavoriteTestResult.TestDetails

Comment: @Jeroen you mean web service?

Comment: No your titanium JS code from the parsing till the outputting.

Comment: :O i make it work, you know how?
I need to convert its inner objects into JSON again and again and it worked.

**JSON.parse(e.GetDoctorFavoriteTestResult)[0].TestID**

Answer (score 0):

Install this chrome extension.It would give you path for titanium app automatically

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en

Thanks

Comment: {
hey: "guy",
anumber: 243,
anobject: {
whoa: "nuts",
anarray: [],
more: "stuff"
},
awesome: true,
bogus: false,
meaning: null,
link: "http://jsonview.com",
notLink: "http://jsonview.com is great"
}

I got this by usign that extention of chrome

Comment: Yes is your json data not formatted now and giving you path for it?

Comment: From where i can get the path?
no any path here in the extention

Comment: sorry to bother you :D
My this extension is not working properly,
Let me fix this first

Comment: Its not working, i have tried on two machines, the extension not showing up.

Comment: Here is the URL,
You may try by yourself

http://www.eclabs.in/SmartService.svc/rest/GetDoctorFavoriteTest/51/~

Comment: I dont think yours is valid json

Comment: but i can access some of values by using JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to see how you are parsing the json

Try this:
GetDoctorFavoriteTestResult[0].TestDetails

Comment: its look like this but its Undefined :(

Comment: I'm looking at this link you just posted and I see that indeed no TestDetails is mentioned http://www.eclabs.in/SmartService.svc/rest/GetDoctorFavoriteTest/51/~

Comment: my apology, i just update the service to make this bad girl run